# What is the probability of a flush in 7 card poker

Tags: probability, poker

Problem:

What is the probability of getting a flush (5 cards of the same suit)
in 7 card poker?

Note: For purposes of this question, a straight  flush or a royal flush
counts as a flush.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the  probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
p &= \dfrac{ 4 { {13} \choose {5}}{ {47} \choose {2} }}
 { {{52} \choose {7}} } \\
p &= \dfrac{ 99 } { 2380 } \\
p &\doteq  0.0415966
\end{align*}

I have good reason to believe the answer is: $0.058511$. Where did  I  go wrong?

Comment: 0.058511 seems high according to [this](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/comp20/). You overcount 6- and 7-card flushes. Each 6-card flush is counted $\binom{6}{5}=6$ times while each 7-card flush is counted $\binom{7}{5}=21$ times

Comment: @BenjaminWang I found a website which, I believe, gave correct probabilities for a flush, straight flush and a royal flush in 7 card poker . I  summed the  three numbers it was 0.058511. I cannot  seem to find the  website now. The 0.058511 could be wrong.

Comment: It is wrong: See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#7-card_poker_hands).  I think you want to sum 5-card flushes and 6-card flushes and 7-card flushes separately to avoid miscounting, so $\frac{ 4 { {13} \choose {5}}{ {39} \choose {2} }}{ {{52} \choose {7}} } + \frac{ 4 { {13} \choose {6}}{ {39} \choose {1} }}{ {{52} \choose {7}} } + \frac{ 4 { {13} \choose {7}}{ {39} \choose {0} }} { {{52} \choose {7}} } = \frac{78639}{2572780} \approx 0.030566.$

Comment: @Henry Now,  I remember where I  computed 0.058511. It was from Wikipedia. The same link your provided. However, I did it  wrong. I  now believe the correct answer is: 0.0306110. I got that by adding the probability of a flush plus the probability of a straight flush plus the probability of a royal flush. With the original post, I used the cumulative probabilities which is wrong,

Comment: The calculation just now by Henry did not account for straight/royal flushes any differently and already has those "included."  No need to add them yet again.  If you *didn't* want straight or royal flushes, then you'll need to be more careful with the $\binom{13}{x}$ terms and do something like subtracting away the straights...

Comment: If you used Wikipedia's $0.0303$ for a non-royal, non-straight flush, then note this is rounded

Comment: In the future... please don't go through the effort of expanding out a binomial like this and simplifying by hand in a post like this.  If you really don't want to use a calculator to simplify fractions, fine... but don't make us suffer through it too.  It is perfectly acceptable to go straight from an expression with binomials to what it finishes evaluating to after simplifications.  You wasted literal dozens of lines here in the post on this.

Comment: As for the underlying issue, if it was not made clear already by now, this is the exact same issue as the other basic problem types like "make a committee such that it has at least one man and at least one woman" and thinking you just pick a man and then pick a woman and then fill in the rest.  You are incorrectly applying some importance to if it was picked first or picked in the "excess."  Consider what happens if your deck just so happened to have only the spades in it.  By your logic the probability might still have been $\binom{13}{5}\binom{8}{2}/\binom{13}{7}>1$ which can't be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of 5.82% is the probability of getting a flush or better. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability#7-card_poker_hands

The probability of getting a flush, excluding royal flush and straight flush, is 3.03%

\begin{aligned}&\left[{4 \choose 1}\times \left[{13 \choose 7}-217\right]\right]\\+&\left[{4 \choose 1}\times \left[{13 \choose 6}-71\right]\times 39\right]\\+&\left[{4 \choose 1}\times \left[{13 \choose 5}-10\right]\times {39 \choose 2}\right]\end{aligned}

The above equals 4,047,644. The derivation is here: [http://people.math.sfu.ca/~alspach/comp20/](http://people.math.sfu.ca/%7Ealspach/comp20/)

The probability of a royal flush is the following,  divided by ${52 \choose 7}$,

$$ {4 \choose 1}{47 \choose 2}$$

The above corresponds to picking a suit, and then 2 arbitrary cards after selecting the 5 sequential ones that correspond to the royal flush.

The probability of a straight flush is the following, divided by ${52 \choose 7}$,

$$ {9 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1}{46 \choose 2}$$

The above corresponds to picking a suit, and a reference card different from ace to start the straight flush, followed by 2 arbitrary cards after selecting the 5 sequential ones that correspond to the straight flush.